# Cant rotate constraint in physic asset

Tags: unreal-engine4

Constraint rotation has no effect in physic asset. I rotate it but nothing changed, arm bends as before. I found a solutions through pushing ALT, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It really rotates with ALT but angles visualy shows not correct